# How to define rescue_from-type handler for ActiveRecord models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Developing in Rails 5.2.2.1. I want to define a "global" rescue handler for my model, so that I can catch `NoMethodError` and take appropriate action. I find that controllers can do this with `rescue_from`, but models cannot. Knowing that the Rails Developers are smart people ;) I figure there must be some Good Reason for this, but I'm still frustrated. Googling around, and I can't even find any examples of people asking how to do this, and other people either telling them how, or why they can't, or why they shouldn't want to. Maybe it's because rescue handlers can't return a value to the original caller?

Here's what I'm trying to do: I need to refactor my app so that what used to be a single model is now split into two (let's call them Orig and New). Briefly, I want to make it so that when an attribute getter method (say) is called against an Orig object, if that attribute has moved to New, then I can catch this error and call `new.getter` instead (understanding that Orig now `belongs_to` a New). This solution is inspired by my experience doing just this sort of thing with Perl5's `AUTOLOAD` feature.

Any ideas of how to get this done are much appreciated. Maybe I just have to define getters/setters for all the moved attributes individually.

Comment: People devise solutions based on what they already know. The word "delegation" was not in my s/w dev vocabulary, and no amount of googling how to catch no-method errors was going to find it for me. Thank you for providing a helpful hint and not being snide at all.

Answer (score 0):

## Overide method_missing :) !?

You could try overriding the `method_missing` method. This could potentially cause confusing bugs, but overriding that method is definitely used to great effect in at least one gem that i know of.

I didn't want to call the class `new` because it is a reserved keyword and can be confusing. So I changed the class name to `Upgraded`.

This should get you started.

```
class Upgraded
  def getter
    puts "Congrats, it gets!"
  end
end

class Original
  def initialize
    @new_instance = Upgraded.new
  end

  def method_missing(message, *args, &block)
    if message == :attribute_getter
      @new_instance.send(:getter, *args, &block)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, *args)
    method_name == :attribute_getter or super
  end
end

c = Original.new
c.attribute_getter
```

- You will have to change names of the getter and setter methods. Because you have a `belongs_to` association you can just use that.

### Or you could try just using delegate_to

like @mu_is_too_short suggests, you could try something like this?

```
class Original < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :upgraded
 delegate :getter_method, :to => :upgraded 
end

class Upgraded < ApplicationRecord
  def getter_method
  end
end
```

Comment: Definitely would be careful with the method missing option given https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb#L15 and https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb#L425

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what I needed to know is the word "[delegation](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/10/delegate-methods-in-ruby/)". It seems there are a variety of ways to do this kind of thing in Ruby, and Rails, and I should have expected that Ruby's way of doing it would be cleaner, more elegant, and more evolved than Perl5. In particular, recent versions of Rails provide "[delegate_missing_to](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23930)", which appears to be precisely what I need for this use case.